# How to check all the nodes on load in jstree even if tie_selection is false

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am new to JStree and please help. My requirements are
1. Load all the nodes in JStree as selected (all parent, child) on loading
2. When the user unchecks a node //perform some action
3. When the user again checks a node //perform some action

Problem here is, I can capture check/uncheck events and perform actions. (2 & 3 is working fine)
I have mentioned
"checkbox":
{
'three_state': true,
'whole_node': false,
'tie_selection': false
}
and because of this, while loading the JStree I am not able to checkall the nodes. Its opened with all the nodes unchecked. I have tried using the below line. 
  $('#jstree').jstree("check_node","j1_1"); //selecting the topnode hoping that it would select all. Failed
  $('#jstree').jstree("check_all"); //failed

Please help me how to load all the nodes as checked.

Comment: So do you want to have all nodes show check mark, but not selection blue box around every node?

Comment: No. I want all the nodes checked on load. It is working now, if i put the statement  $('#jstree').jstree("check_all"); outside the block where i initialise the tree.